# Integral of a function of a square?

Tags: calculus

If the function of a square is $$\mid x\mid+\mid y\mid=c$$ and if i were to take the integral then it would imply $$\mid y\mid=c-\mid x \mid$$ then $$\int\ c-\mid x\mid dx$$ after i solved it i got $$=cx-\frac{x\sqrt x^2}2$$
and i dont understand why because the área of a square is simply l*b=A?

Comment: Firstly this is not a function, but a curve. The area would be $4\int_{0}^{c}(c-x) dx$ (You must take cases on $|y|$ and $|x|$.)

Comment: okay i undertand but even when i took the integral i still got 2c^2