# What did i do wrong when integrating this square?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

If the function of a square is $$∣x∣+∣y∣=c$$and if i were to take the integral then it would imply $$∣y∣=c−∣x∣$$ then $$\int_0^c (c−x)dx$$
afterwhich when i solve it i get $$c^2/2$$ (i did not make anymistakes when integrating this square) which is not the equation for a square which should be $c^2$ can someone please explain what am i missing?

Comment: You just asked this question the other day, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040264/integral-of-a-function-of-a-square – what do you think you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

Yo are missing the fact that the side of the square is not $c$ but $\sqrt2\,c$.

Comment: what i dont understand? are you talking about the upper limit of the integral being √2c?

Comment: @CuriosandKnowledgeable you are assuming the area is $c^2$ because you are assuming the side length is $c$, but after sketching a graph of the Cartesian equation you will see it isn't.

Comment: The integral is correct. One side of the square goes from the point of coordinates $(c,0)$ to the one with coordinates $(0,c)$. Its length is $\sqrt2\,c$, and the area of the square us $2\,c^2$.

Answer (score 0):

You are only integrating over half your shape, shouldn't the limits be between -c and +c (which gives c^2).

And this will only give you the area above the x-axis, you will have to multiply your answer by 2 to get the total area (as shape is symmetric about the x axis).